# R rollapply on glmnet

Tags: r, zoo, glmnet

```
library(zoo)
library(glmnet)
```

I can get the rolling coefficients on a linear regression:

```
seat <- as.zoo(log(UKDriverDeaths))
time(seat) <- as.yearmon(time(seat))
seat <- merge(y = seat, y1 = lag(seat, k = -1),
y12 = lag(seat, k = -12), all = FALSE)



tail(seat)
fm <- rollapply(seat, width = 50,
FUN = function(z) coef(lm(y ~ y1 + y12, data = as.data.frame(z))),
by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
```

but I am having trouble getting the rolling coefficients for glmnet:

```
fm <- rollapply(seat, width = 50,
FUN = function(z) coef(cv.glmnet(z[,c(2,3)],z[,1],alpha=1, data = 
as.data.frame(z))), by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please make your example reproducible and be explicit about what is giving you the issue. Is it giving an error? If so include the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `cv.glmnet` doesn't have a `data` argument. It has `x` and `y` arguments which are the predictor matrix and response vector respectively.

Second, your `seat` dataset has missing values in the first row (unavoidable due to the lag operation). This will mess up glmnet, which has a rather bare-bones interface which does minimal checking.

Third, `coef` on a glmnet/cv.glmnet object returns a sparse matrix, which `rollapply` doesn't know what to do with.

Fixing all of these gives:

```
fm2 <- rollapply(seat, width=50, FUN=function(z)
{
    z <- na.omit(z)
    as.numeric(coef(cv.glmnet(z[, c(2, 3)], z[, 1], alpha=1)))
}, by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

You can also use my [glmnetUtils](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnetUtils) package, which implements a formula/data frame interface to glmnet. This deals with the first two problems above.

```
library(glmnetUtils)
fm3 <- rollapply(seat, width=50, FUN=function(z)
{
    as.numeric(coef(cv.glmnet(y ~ y1 + y12, data=as.data.frame(z), alpha=1)))
}, by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.